# Why logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler creates new log files owned by root?

Tags: logging, mod-wsgi

I want to rotate the logs of a Django / apache2 / wsgi website. But sometimes (not always, which is even more strange) logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler creates new log files owned by root!
So my application doesn't have write access any more to the log, and gives me a server error.

I have specified umask=0007 in my WSGIDaemonProcess setting, but that doesn't help either.

How can that happen? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't happen, even if you were using mod_wsgi embedded mode, as no Python application code would ever be run as root unless you have hacked your Apache source code to disable the security protections in it which prevent you from setting User/Group to root.

Would first up suggest you verify that you are running in daemon mode and thus whether the WSGIDaemonProcess definition is even being used.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Also make sure you aren't using an ancient version of mod_wsgi. In mod_wsgi prior to 3.0 the interpreter would itself be initialised in the Apache parent when running as root, but any code for your application would still be run as a mortal user after sub processes created. But then, if using such an older mod_wsgi version and you were doing really freaky stuff like using a local 'sitecustomize.py' or side affects of loading '.pth' files to setup logging, then you might manage to run stuff as root when you shouldn't.